# ¿Cómo guardo datos en una lista genérica y contar caracteres?

Tags: c#, lista

Tal como el título lo describe, mi objetivo es poder guardar en una lista genérica una cadena de texto (string) y contar que caracter se repite más veces.

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
string cadena;

do {
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un string no vacio: ");
    cadena = Console.ReadLine();
    lista.Add(cadena);
} while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena));

Console.WriteLine("Lista: " + lista);
```

Al imprimir en pantalla la lista recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> System.Collections.Generic;'1[System.String]

El resultado que deseo obtener es la impresión de la lista en pantalla. Y a su vez poder contar que caracter se repite más veces dentro de esa cadena.

*Ejemplo:*

**ENTRADA:**

```
Hola SOO
```

**SALIDA:**

```
LETRA O SE REPITE 3 VECES
```

Un saludo.

Comment: @sstan editado, espero poder haber sido más claro.

Comment: @sstan editado nuevamente, fui más al grano.

Comment: Ir al grano es excelente. Creo que ahora se entiende mejor la pregunta. Solo toma en cuenta que la salida no corresponde con la entrada (no hay 3 ceros) y que tu código realmente no es un intento de cumplir con tu objetivo. De modo que todavía hay lugar para mejorarla. Pero esta mucho mejor.

Comment: @sstan se me escapo el 0, arreglado. El problema es que no sé como seguir si no puedo visualizar la cadena correctamente guardada en la lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no necesitas una lista ni un bucle. Solo necesitas aceptar una cadena `string`. Un `string` ya es en sí como una lista de caracteres sobre la cual puedes ejecutar métodos LINQ.

Por ejemplo, para aceptar una cadena e imprimir el caracter que mas se repite, se puede hacer con una simple expresión LINQ a partir de una variable `string`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un string no vacio: ");
string cadena = Console.ReadLine();

var grouping = cadena
    .GroupBy(c => char.ToLowerInvariant(c))
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First();

Console.WriteLine($"LETRA {grouping.Key} SE REPITE {grouping.Count()} VECES");
```

Nota: Por la pregunta, parece que no haces distinción entre una letra minúscula y mayúscula. Por eso uso la expresión `.GroupBy(c => char.ToLowerInvariant(c))`. Si esto no es lo que quieres, puedes usar `.GroupBy(c => c)`.

Comment: Entiendo perfecto, gracias, si sabía que con LINQ había funciones que te permitían realizar ese tipo de acciones. Una consulta respecto a tu código.
¿Qué significan las  c=>c en la expreción Group.By (.GroupBy(c => c))? Es decir, tienen alguna traducción o la sintaxis es así ?

Comment: Es la sintaxis concisa de los lambdas. Puedes hacer búsqueda sobre los lambdas para aprender a usarlo. Basicamente, es un forma abreviada de expresar una función. En este caso `c => c` equivale a `char GetGroupByKey(char c) { return c; }`.

Comment: Claro, es decir es lo mismo colocar C=>C o X=>X o cualquier caracter (char). ¿Puede ser?

Comment: Eso. `c` es solo el nombre que le asignas al parámetro. Es un nombre de variable como cualquier otra.

Comment: En el código solo se va a mostrar el conteo de primer carácter, para mostrar todos debes cambiar el ".First" de la expresión linq por ". ToList() e iterar esa lista para mostrar el conteo de todos los caracteres

Comment: @Luis: En la pregunta se menciona que solo quería *contar que caracter se repite más veces*.

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar todos los caracteres si vas a necesitar una lista, ya que el código de sstan solo te mostrará el conteo del primer carácter. Para poder mostrar todos, el código de sstan quedaría así:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un string no vacio: ");
var cadena = Console.ReadLine();

var grouping = cadena
    .GroupBy(c => char.ToLowerInvariant(c))
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
   .ToList();
foreach(var grp in grouping)
    Console.WriteLine($"LETRA {grp.Key} SE REPITE {grp.Count()} VECES");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado un string llamado **palabra** y usando LINQ(C# 3.0+) sería algo así:

```
string palabra = "abbbbccd";
var caracteres = (from c in palabra
                    group c by c into g
                    select new
                    {
                        c = g.Key,
                        count = g.Count(),
                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.count);
foreach (var caracter in caracteres)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Carácter " + caracter.c + " aparece " + caracter.count + " veces");
}
```